# How align elements in Xamarin StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am attaching the result of this code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC2Sm.png)

What I want the layout to look like is that the red stays centered and the yellow goes towards the ends of the Horizontal.

And regardless of the text size of the label inside the yellow, I want the red color to remain centered.
please give me advice

```
<StackLayout
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Label x:Name="xTitle"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                Text="asdasdasdas"
                VerticalOptions="Fill" />


            <Label x:Name="xResult"
                BackgroundColor="Goldenrod"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                Text="123123123123123"
                VerticalOptions="Fill" />
        </StackLayout>
```

I tried to send the yellow part to the far end while keeping the red label in the center.

Comment: Stacklayout isn't designed to do what you want. Make a grid with three columns, with `<Grid ... ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto,*" ... >`. Red label with `Grid.Row="1"`. Yellow label with `Grid.Row="2"`, and `HorizontalOptions="End"` and/or `HorizontalTextAlignment="End"`. (I am not sure which is needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use 'Grid' to achieve this, just as ToolmakerSteve mentioned.

Please refer the following code:

```
<StackLayout> 
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1"
               x:Name="xTitle"
               BackgroundColor="Red"
               Text="asdasdasdas"
               VerticalOptions="Fill" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="xResult"
               Text="123123123123123"
               BackgroundColor="Goldenrod"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Fill" 
               HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        
    </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

For more information, you can check [Xamarin.Forms Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid).